# user id mapping failing with nfs and ldap

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, nfs4

I have a NFS4 export (from FreeBSD ZFS filesystem) with root_squash turned off (-maproot=root).

Until recently I've been mounting this drive without problems on several machines (mostly Ubuntu 12.04 server), but all of a sudden I've run into this strange problem:

On three OSes I've tried to setup (Mint 15, Ubuntu 13.04, Ubuntu 12.04 client) I do the ldap and nfs configuration and mount the drives and everything appears fine.  I can see appropriate user and group names mapped from ids.  But if I try to chown any of these files to any other user it always sets them to nobody:nobody.

Note, this does not happen on the older machines.  I've even copied the exact configurations (/etc/idmapd.conf, /etc/ldap*, /etc/pam.d/*) from the older Ubuntu 12.04 machines to the new one and it still won't work!  It also seems mostly restricted to chown.  I can touch new files as any user and they have correct ownership.  I have no idea what's going on.

The only clue I might have gotten is that the broken machines give this error in syslog (after increasing verbosity in idmapd):

```
Sep 10 16:58:48 cabernet rpc.idmapd[1009]: nfs4_name_to_uid: calling nsswitch->name_to_uid
Sep 10 16:58:48 cabernet rpc.idmapd[1009]: nss_getpwnam: name '5000@test.com' domain 'test.com': resulting localname '5000'
Sep 10 16:58:48 cabernet rpc.idmapd[1009]: nss_getpwnam: name '5000' not found in domain 'test.com'
```

While the working machines give:

```
Sep 10 17:03:44 node-2 rpc.idmapd[2906]: nfs4_uid_to_name: calling nsswitch->uid_to_name
Sep 10 17:03:44 node-2 rpc.idmapd[2906]: nfs4_uid_to_name: nsswitch->uid_to_name returned 0
Sep 10 17:03:44 node-2 rpc.idmapd[2906]: nfs4_uid_to_name: final return value is 0
Sep 10 17:03:44 node-2 rpc.idmapd[2906]: Client 18: (user) id "5000" -> name "myname@test.com"
```

So it looks like for some reason the broken machines are trying to use the id as the username.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved via the following setting in http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=500778

```
/etc/idmapd.conf
[General]
Cache-Expiration = 10
```

You can visit http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.nfs/44754